# Is there a way to set the color of the "outline" of the image in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, styles

I have an icon with black lines.  The TabBarController intelligently outlines the black as a color (default blue, but I changed it to red)

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor  = UIColor.redColor()
```

How can I do this in a UIImageView? When I drag the image out and then change the tintColor, nothing happens and it stays black.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an image that you have inserted into your image assets, then make sure that the image is set as a template. Select the image, then where the attribute inspector is, make sure that it is set to "template"

[image: on the right]

Comment: Where do I find "template" on the inspector? Doesn't seem to be found.

Comment: Edited to show picture

Comment: I dragged a UIImageView out. How can I select the image inside that UIImageView?

Comment: If you have inserted into image assets, it is in there that you set it as a template

Comment: I've changed it to template,but how come when I go back to my storyboard to set the tint color of the image view, it stays black?